# Trying to understand how Jekyll redirect works

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions, netlify-cms

I recently moved my site domain from https://rakshitsoral.ga to https://rakshitsoral.com. I want to redirect .ga domain to .com domain. I tried using plugin Jekyll-redirect-from, but it's not working as expected (maybe, I am doing something wrong).

My front YAML matter for index.html currently looks like this:

```
redirect_from: https://rakshitsoral.ga/
redirect_to: https://rakshitsoral.com/
```

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong here. My website is hosted with Netlify.

Comment: How about `<script>window.location.href='https://rakshitsoral.com/';</script>`?